# (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask-sqlalchemy

I am building a website using REST API with Flask-SQLALCHEMY.

I have been trying to add the Update for a specific API.

It gives me an error that says

`(sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type. [SQL: u'SELECT cowgroup.cownumber AS cowgroup_cownumber, cowgroup.groupnumber AS cowgroup_groupnumber, cowgroup.groupname AS cowgroup_groupname, cowgroup.groupdescription AS cowgroup_groupdescription, cowgroup.attributes AS cowgroup_attributes, cowgroup.user AS cowgroup_user \nFROM cowgroup \nWHERE cowgroup.groupnumber = ?'] [parameters: ({'groupname': u'"Test1"', 'cownumber': u'["365","366","367"]', 'user': u'pk@gmail.com', 'attributes': u'["pasturenumber","sex","breed","height","weight","animaltype","status","herd","trial"]', 'groupnumber': u'1011', 'groupdescription': u'"Test1"'})]"`

Views.py code

```
    def patch(self, groupnumber):
    group_query = Group.query.filter_by(groupnumber=groupnumber)
    raw_dict = request.form
    try:
        schemaGroup.validate(raw_dict)
        for key, value in raw_dict.items():
            setattr(group_query, key, value)

        group_query.update(raw_dict)
        return self.get(groupnumber)

    except ValidationError as err:
        resp = jsonify({"error": err.messages})
        resp.status_code = 401
        return resp

    except SQLAlchemyError as e:
        db.session.rollback()
        resp = jsonify({"error": str(e)})
        resp.status_code = 401
        return resp
```

Models.py code

```
class Group(db.Model, CRUD):
__tablename__ = 'cowgroup'
cownumber = db.Column(db.Text)
groupnumber = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
groupname = db.Column(db.Text)
groupdescription = db.Column(db.Text)
attributes = db.Column(db.Text)
user = db.Column(db.Text)

def __init__(self, cownumber, groupnumber, groupname, groupdescription, attributes,user):
    self.cownumber = cownumber
    self.groupnumber = groupnumber
    self.groupname = groupname
    self.groupdescription = groupdescription
    self.attributes = str(attributes)
    self.user = user


class Group_Schema(Schema):
    not_blank = validate.Length(min=1, error='Field cannot be blank')
    id = fields.Integer(dump_only=True)  # WHY DOES THIS HAVE TO BE HERE???
    cownumber = fields.String(validate=not_blank)
    groupnumber = fields.Integer(validate=not_blank)
    groupname = fields.String()
    groupdescription = fields.String()
    attributes = fields.String()
    user = fields.String()

    # self links
    def get_top_level_links(self, data, many):
        if many:
            self_link = "/group/"
        else:
            self_link = "/group/{}".format(data['attributes']['groupnumber'])
        return {"self": self_link}

    class Meta:
        type_ = 'group'
```

You can see the schema here for the data I'll be passing and I'll also put the data I'm passing through just below this.

```
"cownumber": "[\"365\",\"366\",\"367\"]",
"groupnumber": 1011,
"groupname": "Test1",
"user": "pk@gmail.com",
"attributes": "[\"pasturenumber\",\"sex\",\"breed\",\"height\",\"weight\",\"animaltype\",\"status\"]",
"groupdescription": "Test1"
```

Can somebody look into this and help me what I'm doing wrong.
I found related topics but they were in accordance to the "cur.execute"
But i send the data via SQLALCHEMY and raw_dict so that doesn't help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Views.py i had to change a few things:

I'm posting my answer below hope this helps somebody.

```
    def patch(self, groupnumber):
    group_query = Group.query.get_or_404(groupnumber)
    raw_dict = request.form
    try:
        schemaGroup.validate(raw_dict)
        for key, value in raw_dict.items():
            setattr(group_query, key, value)

        group_query.update()
        return self.get(groupnumber)
```